# How to access string inside render function

Tags: php

I would like to access string inside my echo'd render class.

Controller file:

```
$Page = new Page;

$string = "Some data here...";

echo $Page->render();
```

body.php:

```
<body>
  echo '<p>'.$string.'</p>'; //$string returns as 
</body>
```

Render:

```
class Page
{
    public function render(){
       include 'header.php';
       include 'body.php';
       include 'footer.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: Well your variable from the controller file is out of scope in your render function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in these cases the values are sent via parameters. Something like:

```
$Page = new Page;

echo $Page->render(array(
    "string" => "Some data here...",
    "other_variable" => "Some other value here",
));
```

Then you use these values inside your render method:

```
class Page
{
    public function render($values) {
       extract($values);
       include 'header.php';
       include 'body.php';
       include 'footer.php';
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that this is a very simple example only for demonstration purposes!